# Using ASP.Net Core WEB API with ReactJS getting localhost:56391/ws' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Description: Created ASP.NET WEB API Integrated ReactJs. But, After Running I'm getting ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. I don't have any idea.

Steps Followed:

1. Create A Project ASP.NET CORE WEB API (6.0)
2. Create a folder name it client.
3. Ran npx create-react-app .
4. Below are the launchSettings, appsettings and program files.

launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:63871",
      "sslPort": 44382
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "WebApplication1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7018;http://localhost:5028",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
    configuration.RootPath = "client/build";
});

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "client";
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.Run();

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="6.0.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="client\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Could you please, someone help her. what I need to do to overcome this issue.

Actual Result:

[image: In Console we are getting ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR]

[image]

Comment: Do u need SSL ? If not, change the sllPort to 0

Comment: @Camadas, Ive updated sslport to 0.

{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:63871",
      "sslPort": 0
    }

But, in console i still see same error.

localhost:62042/ws' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
WebSocketClient @ WebSocketClient

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code to your Program.cs file

> Make sure your react app run on port 7018

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "CorsPolicy",
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:7018")
                                .AllowAnyHeader()
                                .AllowAnyMethod();
                      });
});
```